# 500 Internal server error for @next/image images when hosting on AWS #27453

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js. When running on AWS, every `@next/image` image isn't loaded. I am getting 500 Internal server errors for every @next/image images when hosting on an AWS EC2. The non-`@next/image` images work fine. Same story on Next 10. Everything works fine on localhost it must be related to AWS.

I am using the commands

```
npx next build
npx next start -p 80
```

Comment: According to some sources online, it appears that to use `next/image` on EC2 you need to use a [loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader) (other than default). Also `as` doesn't work on `next/link` component.